# GitHub contributions used to appear on my profile when using Github Desktop, but it doesn't anymore when I use the VS Code terminal

Tags: git, github

I'm referring to the map of contributions on your GitHub profile. I recently started work and I was initially using GitHub Desktop to make my commits and pull requests and my contributions would show up, but now that I make my commits through the terminal on VS Code, the contributions don't appear on my Github profile.

I've run "git config user.name" and "git config user.email" to double check my info, and it's all correct, as expected since my contributions were being logged before.

Any help on this would really be appreciated. I like the community aspect of GitHub and would love to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you push the commits?

Comment: Yes I did @dan1st

Comment: Are the commits present on the GitHub repository (not on your computer, not VSC, not GitHub Desktop)?

Comment: @dan1st They are, I can see them

Comment: Is the username/email correct, there?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Desktop has its [own user.name/email setting](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/setting-your-commit-email-address#setting-your-commit-email-address-on-github)

It might differ from git config --global user.name/email, that you need to double-check in order to be exactly as your GitHub user account name and email.

> [Add the email address to your account on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account), so that your commits are attributed to you and appear in your contributions graph.